# NetworkImageView. Save image in thumbnail [Server] / resize in client?

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I'm trying to create a CRUD android application. 
Now, when the List Activity is shown, it will display the items created along with a thumbnail of the original image.

What is the best practice for displaying a thumbnail in an Android application with Volley? Should I generate a thumbnail for the images uploaded or just re-size the image at the client side?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with a general answer for this questions because it all depends on how many images you're trying to download and how important showing the thumbnails is.

I would personally generate the thumbnails on the server side as soon as they are uploaded by the user. Doing this has several advantages:

1. All your app has to do is request the thumbnail and render it, which is much simpler and less CPU-intensive than using Volley's `ImageRequest`.
2. Smaller images means less data usage. You definitely don't want your app to download a 10MB 25-megapixel image over a 3G connection just to shrink it to a 100x100 thumbnail that the user might not even care about.

The only drawback that I can think of is that you might have to generate multiple thumbnails, one for each screen size (e.g. one for hdpi screens and another for xxhdpi). This is slightly more expensive on the server side but might make your UI look much better.

Also, remember to cache thumbnails in your app's cache directory so you don't have to re-request them every single time you want to show them.